# Is there a UIView like a WPF Grid?

Tags: ios, layout, xamarin.ios

In iOS is there a UIView to lay out two child views in a column (or row) such that one view has a fixed height (or width) and the other view expands to fill the empty space?

WPF has the [System.Windows.Controls.Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) class, for example.  I would use it to solve this problem as follows:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="123" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="I have a fixed height" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="My height expands to fill the empty space" />
</Grid>
```